# Activating conda environment without separate Python version in IDEs

Tags: python, ide, anaconda, conda

I recently created a conda environment (in Ubuntu 16.04), which is working great from the command line. I can activate it with no problems, the packages are properly separated, etc.

However, because it is running the same version of Python as the Anaconda installation (Python 3.6.1), it has not created a separate interpreter. Within the /anaconda3/envs folder there are no other folders. This makes it difficult when I want to use editors (such as vscode and Pycharm) because they cannot find the path to some of the packages I have installed in the environment. I would love to start using the great debugging features in Pycharm but without a separate interpreter I have no idea where to even start. Is there a way to initialize the interpreter in the correct environment?

When I run conda info --envs, this is what I get:

```
# conda environments:
#
chatbot                  /home/bradley/.conda/envs/chatbot
tensorflow               /home/bradley/.conda/envs/tensorflow
tf_testing               /home/bradley/.conda/envs/tf_testing
root                  *  /home/bradley/anaconda3
```

If I try to run the Python in these directories (a small executable script exists), it doesn't include all the packages. Should I maybe add an environment variable? If so, what would I write?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `conda info --envs`? Regardless of the Python version, a folder should be created in the `envs` folder

Comment: @darthbith, I edited the question to include that information.